# Set insert trigger - value to highest value in column + 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a lists table with the following columns

```
lists:
- id
- category_id
- name
- sort_order
```

When adding a new row to the table I want to set the value of the sort order to the highest sort order value + 1 where the category_id is the same as the new row's category_id. Is there a way to achieve this?

***UPDATE***
So with the recommnendation to create an insert trigger I tried this

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_list_sort_order()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.sort_order := select (select sort_order from lists where category_id = NEW.category_id order by sort_order DESC limit 1) + 1
  RETURN NEW;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER set_list_sort_order_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON lists
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_list_sort_order()
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 4:   NEW.sort_order := select (select sort_order from lists w...
```

Comment: Have you tried using an insert trigger?

Comment: What happens when you have two simultaneous inserts? Should they both get the same value?

Comment: You should be using a sequence to generate those numbers. Any approach using `max() + 1` is either extremely slow and won't scale or is simply broken.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can a sequence be based on another column value? Like in my example the category_id?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a trigger.  Or you can set up the logic directly in the `insert`:

```
insert into lists (category_id, name, sort_order)
    select category_id, name,
           coalesce(max(sort_order) + 1, 1)
    from (values (?, ?)) v(category_id, name) left join
         lists l
         using (category_id)
    group by v.category_id, v.name;
```

Note that a query like this could have race conditions.  So, you might want to go the route of using a trigger.

Comment: thxs man how could I go about setting a trigger with the specified logic?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create stored procedure with something like this:

```
DEClARE @category_id INT = 1

;WITH NextNum AS 
(
    SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN MAX(Table1.sort_order) IS NULL THEN 1 
                ELSE MAX(Table1.sort_order) + 1
            END AS NextValue 
    FROM Table1 AS Table1
    WHERE Table1.category_id = @category_id
) 
INSERT INTO Table1
(
    id
    category_id
    name
    sort_order
)
SELECT  @id, 
        @category_id
        @name 
        NextNum.NextValue
    FROM NextNum
```

Comment: That is invalid for Postgres